# Error in php code, not update date table

Tags: php, mysql

I have unsub.php code:

```
<?php 
include("config.inc.php");
$id=$_REQUEST['id'];
$time=$_REQUEST['t'];
$cid=0;
if(isset($_REQUEST['cid']))
$cid=$_REQUEST['cid']

if($cid==0)
mysql_query("update email_advt set unsubstatus=1 where id=$id AND time=$time");
else
{
if($mysql->total(email_advt","id=$id AND time=$time")>0)
mysql_query("delete from ea_em_n_cat where eid=$id AND cid=$cid");
}

?><!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd"><html>
<head>
<title> Unsubscribe Email</title>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=iso-8859-1">
</head>

<body>
Your email has been successfully unsubscribed from our mailing list. <br>
</body>
</html>
```

And this tables:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `email_advt` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `email` varchar(250) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `unsubstatus` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `time` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  UNIQUE KEY `email` (`email`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM  DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 AUTO_INCREMENT=4 ;

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `ea_em_n_cat` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `eid` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `cid` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM  DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 AUTO_INCREMENT=7 ;
```

When access unsub.php?id=1&t=1360306174&cid=0
Not show Your email has been successfully unsubscribed from our mailing list.
What is wrong ? unsubstatus not set to 1 when acces unsub.php?id=1&t=1360306174&cid=0

Comment: That's not even valid PHP syntax.

Comment: You are using [an **obsolete** database API](http://stackoverflow.com/q/12859942/19068) and should use a [modern replacement](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqlinfo.api.choosing.php).  You are also **vulnerable to [SQL injection attacks](http://bobby-tables.com/)** that a modern API would make it easier to [defend](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/best-way-to-prevent-sql-injection-in-php) yourself from.

Comment: In your query. mysql_query("update email_advt set unsubstatus=1 where id=$id AND `time`=$time"); add a ` to time, so it will be `time`. You are having this problem because time is a built-in function in MySQL. Sorry, grave accent is not showing well on time. Add a grave accent to your `time` column.

Comment: Don't ask questions where the problem is described as "It isn't working". Do some debugging. Tell us the error messages you get. Trace data through the code. Tell us where in the code you think it is breaking.

Comment: Not show error message! Only blank page !

Comment: **That's not valid PHP syntax.** A blank page would fit that as a symptom.

Answer (score 0):

use this query, you missed backticks `` ` ``

```
mysql_query("update email_advt set `unsubstatus`=1 where `id`=$id AND `time`=$time");
```

Comment: what if the user doesn't put backticks around the column names?

Comment: @JW. `time` is reserved word in `mysql` and it is used as column name here, because of that the query was failing.

Comment: yes `TIME` is a reserved keyword but it is permitted without backticks just like `DATE`.

Answer (score 0):

I think you have the error here:

`if($mysql->total(email_advt","id=$id AND time=$time")>0)`

try

`if($mysql->total("email_advt"," id=$id AND time=$time")>0)`

though I'm not really sure what you are trying to get or the arguments of the `total()` method.

Comment: what does this code do? `$mysql->total("email_advt"," id=$id AND time=$time")`?

Comment: what is the parameter list?

Answer (score 0):

If you are using a built-in function as a column name you need to enclosed it in a grave accent. i.e in your query you are using a column `time` which is a built-in function in MySQL.